# Do not called function -mapView:didUpdateUserLocation

Tags: ios7, mkmapview

-mapView:didUpdateUserLocation function does not called in my new app. It is base on iOS 7 and Xcode 5.

that function will be called in the simulator, but it can not called on the iPhone 5(iOS7).
and got the fllowing error

> 2013-10-15 22:34:18.754 FloweryFairy-iOS7[3879:a0b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x9dc8540  (not loaded)
>
> Oct 15 22:34:19 Hseecoms-iMac.local FloweryFairy-iOS7[3879] : CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 5 integer bits/component; 16 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast; 512 bytes/row.
>
> 2013-10-15 22:34:19.164 FloweryFairy-iOS7[3879:9303] vImage decode failed, falling back to CG path.